# Show that $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I must show that  $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$. I know we have to show that $\sqrt{a-b}\ge \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{a + b} \le \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M(>0)\in\mathbb{R}$, then clearly $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous $[0,M]$ which is a closed and bounded set. Then $\sqrt{x}$ is uniform continuous on $[0,M]$.

Also $g'(x)$ is bounded on $[M,\infty)$.**(by what?)** Hence $g$ is uniform continuous on $[M,\infty)$. Club the two statements.

Comment: I doubt you will get very far with that. The two intervals should have nontrivial overlap if you don't want to appeal to the Heine-Cantor theorem a second time.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: If $\{I_1,...,I_n\}$ is a finite set of intervals, and $f$ is uniformly continuous on each $I_r$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_1\cup...\cup I_n$

Comment: @TonyK Yes, because $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact and you can apply the Heine-Cantor theorem. Try to write down the proof of your statement explicitly using $\epsilon-\delta$, and you will run into problems if your intervals are like $[a,b] \cup [b,c]$.

Comment: Suppose $I_1$ and $I_2$ have a single point in common, as you suggest. Then if $|x-y| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon/2$ separately for $x,y \in I_1$ and $x,y \in I_2$, we have $|x-y| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$ for $x,y \in I_1 \cup I_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \leqslant|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| $, we have

$$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 \leqslant |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}|= |(\sqrt{x})^2 - (\sqrt{y})^2|=|x - y|.$$

Hence,  $|x-y| < \delta = \epsilon^2 \implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \epsilon$, for all $x,y \in [0,\infty).$

Comment: Would this be using the sqrt(a-b) and what not that I mentioned? @RRL

Comment: @juniormath:  $\sqrt{a-b}$ need not be considered.  You just need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|a-b|< \delta$ implies $|g(a) - g(b)| = |\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}|< \epsilon$ for all $a,b$.  The key is to use the inequality $|\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}| \leqslant |\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}|$ and, of course,  $|\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}||\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}|= |(\sqrt{a})^2 - (\sqrt{b})^2|= |a - b|$ .